# depth buffer in LibGdx no job

Tags: java, libgdx

it code render rendering my game and he dont job depth buffer(i am make video) https://vk.com/videos183630146?z=video183630146_456239060%2Fpl_183630146_-2
my code rendering and loading models =>

```
  private void LoadingComplete() { // load model
    UBJsonReader reader = new UBJsonReader();
    ModelLoader loader = new G3dModelLoader(reader);
    modelInstance = new ModelInstance(loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("models/mapv2/mapCompl.g3db");
}  
@Override
public void render(float delta) { 
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    camController.update();
    camera.update();

    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    modelBatch.render(modelInstance);
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing `Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);`